# How can we get path params in falcon middleware, if any path param in the route?

Tags: python, python-requests, falconframework, falcon

My routes are as follows:

```
app.add_route('/v1/my_route', MyResource())
app.add_route('/v1/my_route/{app_id}', MyResource())
app.add_route('/v1/my_route2/any_route', AnyRouteResource())
app.add_route('/v1/my_route2/any_route/{app_id}', AnyRouteResource())
```

and Middleware is something similar to

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, req, resp):
        /** Here i want to get <app_id> value if it is passed **/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get every attribute of the request object from `req`. For example, to get the path of your resource:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, req, resp):
        path = req.path

        # process your path here
```

Check the [docummentation](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html) for more info about requests.

If you want to get the app_id directly, just [extend](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/middleware.html#middleware) the method with params, falcon will do the job.

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
        def process_request(self, req, resp, params):
            app_id = params["app_id"]
```

Comment: I have to parse req.path this way, that I don't want to do, anyways got the answer from @Mikhail

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying. Do you mean you whant to parse the Uuid from the path?

Comment: yes, I wanted <app_id> in middleware, which is in path params.

Comment: Then you just need to add an argument to the middleware the param. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is process_resource(self, req, resp, resource, params) method in the base middleware. You can override it. There params is a dict like object with params extracted from the uri template fields.

https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/middleware.html